# how to change the text of my <p> using jquery

Tags: jquery

My jQuery is very rusty, but I am calling from an API and the response is appearing in the console.log just fine, but it wont populate the `<p>` tags when the page loads. I keep getting this error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

My object is fine as its pulling through in the console.log, so I assume its my jQuery.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "LondonsWeather";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>LondonsWeather</h2>

 <p id ="timezone"></p>
 <p id ="time"></p>
 <p id ="currently"></p>



<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get("@Url.Action("GetLondonsWeather", "Weather")",
        function(response) {


            console.log(response.timezone);
            console.log(response.currently.time);
            console.log(response.currently.summary);
            console.log(response.currently.temperature);


            $.("#timezone").text(response.timezone);
            $.("#time").text(response.time);
            $.("#currently").text(response.currently.summary);

        });

});
```

Comment: Not `$.("#timezone")` but `$("#timezone")`. No need of that period.

Comment: that fixed it! How embaressing....jQuery needs some serious work haha./

Comment: That's not a jQuery issue.  That a syntax issue.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this, You are making a typo mistake. Its a perfect jQuery Syntax.

```
$("#timezone").text(response.timezone);
$("#time").text(response.time);
$("#currently").text(response.currently.summary);
```

Comment: There is a close as off topic reason for "simple typographical issues".